# Receiving a 500 internal server error when I have a '%' symbol in the query string

Tags: c#, .net, url

I am trying to diagnose a problem that a client site has come across.  Basically when you do an address search on their website you can specify a `%` symbol for wildcard searches.  For example you can search for `Be%` to return `Belfast` etc.

This queries the database and then redirects you to the results page, passing the search criteria in the querystring for example `results.aspx?criteria=Search%20criteria%20is%20Be%`

This caused problems if you searched for something like `%Belf` as `%Be` is a reserved character in URL encoding.  I therefore coded it to replace `%` with `%25` (URL encoding representation of `%` symbol).  This works fine on my test machine, where the URL is now `results.aspx?criteria=Search%20Criteria%20is%20%25Be` .

This however doesn't work on our clients website for some reason and I can't work out why.  The page keeps error-ing with:

> Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error. The request was rejected by the
>   HTTP filter. Contact the server administrator. (12217)

any time you search for something like `%Be` `%Fa` `%Fe` etc etc

Does anyone know if there is an IIS setting for this or something similar?

Comment: Nope sorry, I ended up just performing the wildcard query then stripping out the percent symbol from the URL

Answer (score 3):

You might have [URLScan](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc242650.aspx) installed on your server.  URLScan intercepts requests and reject them if it detects invalid characters.  It is meant to protect your website from malicious attacks and SQL injection.  If you don't configure it correctly then it will reject perfectly reasonable requests.  Take a look at the ISAPI filters on your website and see if URLScan is there.

Comment: No there isn't anything in the ISAPI filters list, that's why I'm confused, IIS seems to be configured exactly how I have it configured on my test VM

Comment: Make sure you're looking in the right place.  In IIS6, right click the folder named Website and look at its ISAPI filters.  URLScan does not show in the actual websites ISAPI filter list.

Also, have you checked your IIS logs?

Answer (score 2):

Could this solve your problems? It is written by **Zubair Alexander** at http://blog.techgalaxy.net/archives/2521

[image]